# How to use get_the_title with text on the 'alt' of the_thumbnail array?

Tags: post-thumbnails, get-the-title

I'm currently using `<?php the_post_thumbnail('250px', array('class'=>"review-siteshot", 'alt' => get_the_title() )); ?>`

I know that `'alt' => "review"` will output review as all text.

I'm trying to use `get_the_title()` along with "review" so that I get **title-text review** as my alt text for the thumbnail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
'alt' => get_the_title(). ' review'
```

So the full code would be:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('250px', array('class'=>"review-siteshot", 'alt' => get_the_title(). ' review' )); ?>
```

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail()` escapes its own attributes, so it's not necessary here.

Comment: Indeed, Cheers Jacob!

Answer (score 0):

The function [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) can be used to append a string and to return instead of echoing:

```
the_title( '', ' review', 0 )
```

In case stripping tags and escaping is necessary, the function [`the_title_attribute()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_attribute/) can be used:

```
the_title_attribute( [ 'after' => ' review', 'echo' => 0 ] )
```